# Is there a way to export baidu map data same as osm?

Tags: openstreetmap, baidu, baidu-map

I need to use osm data to draw a graph, but its data of some area in China is not complete, while I'm sure Baidu map provides detailed data, but I'm not sure how to export it in the same format as OSM.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Does Baidu even offer a map export? If so, you will need a converter.